# What is the tense of this sentence: Nous sommes allés faire une promenade

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, temps-composés

What is the tense of this sentence?

> Nous sommes allés faire une promenade.

So far, I have learned about passé composé, futur proche, and passé proche. However, none of them seem to fit here.

Comment: Note that this is stilted French. In real life: *On est allés faire une promenade* or *On a été faire une promenade.*

Comment: Ou encore: _nous sommes allés nous promener_.

Comment: @Frank Mieux : *On est allés se promener*. Le pronom sujet *nous* a disparu de la quasi totalité des registres du français parlé.

Comment: @jlliagre À ce point? Bon, ok :-)

Comment: @jlliagre En tant que sujet, je suppose? On a encore besoin de _nous_ dans d'autre cas, non? Par exemple: _il nous a dit_, _ils viennent vers nous_...

Comment: @jlliagre It should be *"On est allé"*, not *"On est allés"*

Comment: @Stef Ça se discute, mais je préfère l'accorder avec le sujet réel. Il ne s'agit pas d'un *on* générique ici mais d'un substitut de *nous*. Quand *on* se substitue à un *tu* féminin, on fait bien l'accord en genre : *Alors, on est grande maintenant !*

Comment: @Frank J'ai bien écrit "pronom sujet". *Nous* est toujours bien sûr présent dans les autres cas: *Nous, on aime qu'on nous offre des cadeaux !*

Comment: @jlliagre Oops! Effectivement, j'ai lu trop vite. Je regardais l'entrée de TLFi sur "on" tout à l'heure, et c'est un très vieux mot apparemment. Je vais continuer à lire pour voir si dans le passé, il a été utilisé dans d'autres fonctions que sujet.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça me rappelle (de très loin) un accord ambigu dans un vers de Baudelaire: _Aux couleurs du couchant reflété par mes yeux_. Baudelaire aurait pu accorder aussi bien avec _couleurs_ qu'avec _couchant_.

Comment: Franchement vos débats sur la pertinence de l'utilisation de "nous" ou de "on", et de l'accord du participe passé n'aident pas à répondre à la question... Il est parfaitement correct de dire "nous sommes allé faire une promenade" et personnellement je suis largement assez vieux jeu pour utiliser régulièrement cette formulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's also **passé composé**. This is the verb **aller** conjugated with the auxiliary **être**. You may be used to seeing the use of the auxiliary **avoir**, as in the sentence "j'ai couru pendant toute la promenade", but for some verbs we use the auxiliary **être**.

For some verbs you can use both, each giving a different meaning to the action.

With the **être** auxiliary, the past participle, in this case **allés**, is conjugated in the plural with the subject, in this case "nous". That's why we put an **s** at the end.

This sentence expresses a past action that you could simply translate it as: we went for a walk.

I'd say it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the present: in French, we use the passé composé a lot, to the detriment of other past tenses like **passé simple** or **imparfait**.

Comment: I just googled "liste des verbes se conjuguant avec l'auxiliaire être" and sadly the first 20 pages in the results were wrong. Google results are not reliable :(

Comment: @Hippo, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

One English translation is "*we went to take a walk.*"

In English, the verb is *went*, in the simple past, and *to take* is an infinitive complement of the verb. In French, the verb is *sommes allés*, in the passé composé, and *faire* is a complement of the verb.

I'm not entirely sure of the French grammatical terms, but *faire* plays the same role in French as *take* does in English. I believe it's called a COD (complément d'objet direct), and in this case the COD happens to be an infinitive.

Comment: The "golden" rule is: *“quand deux verbes se suivent le deuxième est à l'infinitif* (except of course when the 1st one is an auxiliary). The second verb is indeed complement of the 1st one, not sure offhand it it's always COD, it is here anyway.

Comment: @None: I guess that in English, we have both gerund complements (*I suggested going to a movie*) and infinitive complements (*I wanted to go to a movie*). And in French, the golden rule says that verb complements are always infinitive, so the phrase *complément infinitif* would be redundant, which is why I don't remember seeing it anywhere.

Comment: @PeterShor Upon quick verification, _complément infinitif_ doesn't seem to show up in LBU 14th, so it's probably called something else.

Comment: I've only seen it used in academic papers (and even then rarely). Not identified as such in the grammar taught at school

Comment: It seems that the same problem/nuance exists in English: why *We went to take a walk* rather than *We took a walk*? (Though the first phrase might be suggested by the analogy with *We went for a walk*.)

Comment: @PeterShor, thanks for the English translation. it makes the sentence clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a construction that involves two verbs, the first one being a verb of motion ("aller" in this case), always conjugated, and  the second one some other verb of an allowed sort (a  numerous kind), always in the infinitive. Here is the definition for "aller".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller)) 3. [Aller est suivi d'un inf. marquant le but, le plus souvent non précédé de la prép. pour; avec éventuellement un adv. ou un compl. de lieu entre *aller* et l'inf.] **Se mettre en mouvement pour faire quelque chose**.
>
> - Aller voir un ami

It follows that you have to consider the tense of "aller" which is easily seen to be  the "passé composé"; the tense and mode of "faire" are "présent" and "infinitif", respectively.

"Faire une promenade" is a "complement circonstanciel de but"; the equivalent in English grammar is "adverbial" (adjunct of purpose).

*Some usual verbs as first element (not all verbs of motion enter into this construction)*

- aller, venir, partir, revenir, sortir,

*Examples*

- Elle va chercher sa fille à l'école. — Elle va à l'école chercher sa fille. (*option of position for CC de lieu*)
- Il part souvent pêcher à la campagne. (*possibility of insertion of an adverb*)
- Ils sont revenus (pour) prendre leurs affaires. (*sometimes "pour" is optional and does not change the meaning*)
- Ils viennent parfois dire bonjour.
- nous étions partis chercher des provisions.
- Il est allé étudier à l'université.
- Le planton est sorti vérifier les papier de l'automobiliste.
- <s>Il a sauté décrocher le pompon.</s> (*not idiomatic*)
- Il a sauté pour décrocher le pompon. (*correct*)

Comment: Looks like a small typo on "ils sont revenu(s)"

Comment: @LPH, thanks for the explanation.